# Getting data from javascript function on to ASP.NET MVC Controller's Action Method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have looked at many posts on SO to figure out my situation but with not much success. I'm trying to send data from a javascript function(DropdownChange()) to MVC controllers Action method as a parameter based on the dropdown value that is selected on the view. Here is my code:

In .cshtml
     //code for dropdown
     ....followed by
     //code for creating a new plan

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("ActionMethod")">
           <i class="sth" id="sth" Title="Create"></i>
      </a>
```

In .JS file, function to get dropdown change value

```
  function DropdownChange(){
       var Value = parseInt($("#dropDownId").val());
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@ Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Home")',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: "json",
           data: {data : JSON.Stringify(Value)},
           success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
           error: error: function (result){
                  alert('error');
                }
           });
```

and Here is my Controller action method

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult  ActionMethod(string Value)
     {
         // do something with Value     
     }
```

All I'm getting is an error alert message and a JS runtime error along with a null value for Value parameter. Can any one help me in this scenario. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of element is `#dropDownId` and what is its value? Also you should probably just send `data: { value: Value }` in the AJAX request

Comment: Please add the js error message

Comment: `data: Value` should be enough, i think

Comment: try just simply `data: Value` and remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`, it shouldn't be necessary. You aren't sending JSON, nor are you sending a string, you're sending a simple integer. Ideally the controller method should accept `int` since by using `parseInt` on the client I can clearly see the intention is to send an int. This will help with validation of the input.

Comment: What error? Show the relevant information in your question, including the html for your `<select>` and how you call that function. And its `data: { Value: $("#dropDownId").val() }` and remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` (and if the value is an `int`, then the parameter should be `int value`)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@ Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Home")',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: "json",
           data: JSON.stringify({data: Value}),
           success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
           error: error: function (result){
                  alert('error');
                }
           });
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@ Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Home")',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: "json",
           data: Value,
           success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
           error: error: function (result){
                  alert('error');
                }
           });
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you explained why this code should fix the problem, and also what the difference between your two options is, for the benefit of future readers